# How to solve error - Illegal parameter number in definition of \AP@

Tags: afterpage

I'm new to Latex and struggling to properly format a specific cover for my article.

I have the following code that fulfils what is expected from it and even compiles. However, the *"Illegal parameter number in definition of \AP@"* error appears when compiled.

What needs to change for the error to disappear?

```
\usepackage{afterpage}    
\afterpage{
    \newgeometry{textwidth=\paperwidth, textheight=\paperheight, noheadfoot, nomarginpar}
    \newenvironment{capa}[2]{
        \begin{list}{}{
            \setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}
            \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}
            \setlength{\listparindent}{0pt}
            \setlength{\itemindent}{0pt}
            \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}
            \setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
        }
    \item[]}{\end{list}}
    \definecolor{grayish}{RGB}{89,89,89}

    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{xxxxxxxx} \\
    \begin{capa}{7.9cm}{1.9cm}
    \vspace*{65mm} 
    \noindent{
    \textcolor{grayish}{\LARGE{xxxxxxxxx}}}
    \vspace*{9mm}\\
    \textcolor{grayish} {\LARGE { \noindent{ \textbf{xxxxxxxx}}} \\}
    \vspace*{50mm}
    \noindent { \textcolor{grayish} {\large{xxxxxxxxx}} \\ \\ 
    \textcolor{grayish} {\large{xxxxxxxxx}}} \\
    \\
    \noindent {\textcolor{grayish} {\large{xxxxxxx }}\\
    \textcolor{grayish} {\large{ \textit {xxxxxxxx}}}}
    \vspace*{30mm}
    \Small {ffffefefefe}
    \newpage
    \end{capa}
    \restoregeometry}
```

Thanks for the help!
Cheers.

Comment: in the definition of `capa`, use `##1` and `##2` not `#1` and `#2`. But `\newenvironment` will work only once, it would be better to move this definition to somwhere else.

Comment: It solved my problem! Thank you very much!
I do want the newenvironment to work only in this case :)

Comment: you are lucky the LaTeX team has not made `\newenvironment` preamble-only...